# Pickle multiple files in a directory

Tags: python, pickle

So I wanted to figure out a way to read multiple text files in a directory and pickle them together to form a data.pkl file.

So far I tried as below:

Code:

```
 import _pickle as cPickle

 file1=open('/home/mustafa/data/raw.en/raw.en','rb')
 obj=[file1.read()]
 pickle.dump(obj,open('data.pkl','wb'),4)
```

There are about 2 dozen text files labeled as englishText_1 , englishText2 and so on.

Comment: you're trying to add the files' contents to lists and then pickle those lists to a pkl file?

Comment: I'm trying to pull all these text files into 1 pkl file

Comment: Or load each document into a list then pickle that list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How you use the data would dictate how you would want to save each file. If the file names aren't necessary, then iterating over each file in a directory and just saving the contents to a list and then dumping that list to a pickle file would suffice. If you need to save file names, attributes, etc then I would recommend creating a class to save that information to; ie

```
class FileData(object):
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = path
        with open(path, "rb") as fileobj:
            self.data = fileobj.read()
        # add whatever other attributes you want to save here
```

and then add the FileData instances to a list or another class and dump that to a file.

```
file_list = []
for name in os.listdir(folder_path):
    path = os.path.join(folder_path, name)
    if not os.path.isfile(path):
        continue
    file_list.append(FileData(path))

with open(pkl_path, "wb") as fileobj:
    cPickle.dump(file_list, fileobj)
```

Comment: File names would not be necessary. I only added it above to describe how they look like

Comment: I changed the "rb" path into the directory im reading from and I changed the folder_path to the directory im reading from as well

Comment: Error :  IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/home/mustafa/data/raw.en/raw.en'

Comment: Its from this line with open(path, "rb") as fileobj:

Comment: and this line : file_list.append(FileData(path))

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pk4.py", line 14, in <module>
    file_list.append(FileData(path))
  File "pk4.py", line 7, in __init__
    with open('/home/mustafa/data/raw.en/raw.en', "rb") as fileobj:

Comment: the error is telling you that `raw.en` is not a folder. Your path is showing a folder named `raw.en` which I doubt you have

Comment: my files are within the directory: '/home/mustafa/data/raw.en/raw.en'

Comment: I updated the answer to include a check to make sure that the path is a file

Comment: okay i will test it now, also, my os.listdir and my "rb" directory should be the same yes?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143726/discussion-between-user2682863-and-silas).

Comment: what is 'pkl_path' here? @Silas

Comment: @be_real it's the location of the file that you want to save the serialized data to